# Errors: -Xdiag and String cannot be converted to int

Tags: java, string, compiler-errors, int, type-conversion

I am using BlueJ. My assignment is to complete the method "zool" and then complete the methods "printAmerican" and "printEuropean". Then, complete the main method to call the other three; but, I get these errors:

> Recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full ouput.
>   Incompatible type-cannot convert String to int for this line:
>
> `printAmerican ("enter day of the week","enter month", "enter date", "enter year");`

Below is all the code:

```
public class Lab6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        zool (11, "name of your pet", "name of your street");
        // call the method print American
        // call the method printEuropean
        printAmerican ("enter day of the week","enter month", "enter date", "enter year");
        printEuropean ("enter day of the week","enter month", "enter date", "enter year");
    }

    public static void zool (int a, String pet, String street){
        //print the values of a, pet, and street
        a = 11;
        pet = "Fluffy";
        street = "Broadway"; 
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(pet);
        System.out.println(street);
    }

    public static void printAmerican(String day, String month, int date, int year){
        //print in American format. Example: Sunday, September 13, 2015.
        day = Sunday;
        month = September;
        date = 13;
        year = 2015;
        System.out.println(printAmerican);       
    }

    public static void printEuropean(String day, int date, String month, int year){
        //print in Europea format. Example: Sunday, 13 September, 2015.
        day = Sunday;
        date = 13;
        month = September;
        year = 2015;
        System.out.println(printEuropean);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code, such as:

- the method `printAmerican()` takes arguments `String, String, int, int` but you are calling it with `String, String, String, String`
- similarly with `printEuropean()`
- you are supposed to use the arguments that were passed to the methods, but instead you are assigning new values to them
- `System.out.println(printAmerican);` doesn't make sense - `printAmerican` is a name of a method, you can't print it with `println()` like that
- the methods currently aren't doing anything useful even if they could be compiled (with the possible exception of `zool()` which would do what the comment says if you removed the variable assignments)

Please review any materials you have for this assignment, and ask if you have a specific question about some problem.